# Openlayers 3 debug

Tags: openlayers-3

Currently, I am using the compiled version through this link:

But when something goes wrong, it is not possible to debug, because the library is minimized.

Is there a way to link to some file which contains the full source code?

Some weeks ago, I used to us ol-whitespace.js, but now I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see your link but this file is now called ol-debug.js.
You can find it next to ol.js in the build folder.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify Christophe's answer, the OpenLayers Quick Start guide points you to the following minified file:

`<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

You can replace this with:

`<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`